# Cannot fetch HTML element added via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, mutation-observers

As title states, I am having trouble accessing an HTML element that was added with JavaScript. I am trying to fetch a DOM element using document.getElementById('sampleID') after adding an HTML div using JavaScript. However, the HTML source code does not reflect the change made so I can't actually fetch the new element.

The application is very similar to a ToDo list but tracks applications instead of tasks. There is a checkbox included in the div of each application submitted and the POST request still goes through, thus deleting the application from the database, but it is not reflected in the page until being refreshed.

The only related concept I have stumbled upon is the MutationObserver interface for JavaScript which doesn't seem to allow for accessing the added elements.

All suggestions are appreciated!

```
$('#applicationDelete').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Stops browser from navigating away from page
    var names = [];
    $(":checkbox").each(function () {
        var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
        if (isChecked) {
            names.push($(this).attr("class"));
        }
    });
    var data = { names: names }
    console.log('Data: ' + names);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: window.location + 'applications/delete',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res) {
            if (res.response == 'success') {
                var application;
                for (i in names) {
                    application = document.getElementById(names[i]);
                    application.parentNode.removeChild(application);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT:

```
function addApplication(application) {
    const container = document.getElementsByClassName('applicationDelete')[0];
    const appWrap = document.createElement('div');
    appWrap.classList.add('application-wrapper');

    // ADDED THIS LINE THANKS TO SUGGESTIONS!
    appWrap.id = application.company;

    const checkbox = document.createElement('div')
    checkbox.classList.add('checkbox');
    const check = document.createElement('input');
    check.type = 'checkbox';
    check.classList.add(application.company);
    const app = document.createElement('div')
    app.classList.add('application');

    checkbox.appendChild(check);
    appWrap.appendChild(checkbox);
    appWrap.appendChild(app);
    container.insertBefore(appWrap, container.childNodes[3]);

    app.innerHTML = '\
    Company: ' + application.company + '<br>\
    Position: ' + application.position + '<br>\
    Experience: ' + application.experience + '<br>\
    Source: ' + application.source + '<br>';
```

}

Apologies for spaghetti code! I am sure my use of classes and ID's is far from proper coding convention but you guys still managed to find my mistake (without even seeing the addApplication method). Thank you!

Comment: Please post the code you have that isn't working so we have an idea of what's going on and can try to debug it.

Comment: Apologies, I know that's a must on stackoverflow. I had assumed it was a common issue.

Comment: You add the class to the names array but you try to get the elements by id.

Comment: It looks like you're retrieving the *class* of elements and pushing to `names`, which is not the same as an `id`..?

Comment: Spot on! You didn't even see my addApplication code but you were right. I wasn't assigning the ID to the div holding the new application. Completely went over my head. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are pussing class names to the names array with this.

```
names.push($(this).attr("class"));
```

And retrieve the elements by id.

```
application = document.getElementById(names[i]);
```

You should store id's in the names array (I would choose different name for the array too, it suggests you store names).

```
 names.push($(this).attr("id"));
```

Or get the elements with one of the following.

```
document.getElementsByClassName(names[i]); //returns array

document.querySelector('.' + names[i]); //returns dom element

$('.' + names[i]); //returns jQuery object.
```

Since you use jQuery I suggest to use a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 0):

Under the `isChecked` check, you're pushing the element's `class` attribute to the `names` array:

```
names.push($(this).attr("class"));
```

This means that your `names` array consists of `classes` that can be found in the DOM, but you're later looking for `ID`s. The simplest fix is to swap `document.getElementById(names[i]);` for `.querySelector()` method:

```
document.querySelector(names[i]);
// or via jQuery:
$(`.${names[i]}`)
```

☝️ but that's only if you can ensure that your classes are unique (since `querySelector()` finds the *first* element that matches the passed query selector).

However, a more elegant solution is to *use* IDs instead of classes, since the HTML spec demands them to be unique to begin with (which grants you the fail-safety that you haven't written or generated duplicated classes). So given that all of your checkboxes now have unique ID-s:

```
names.push($(this).attr("id"));
// now you can look for ID-s again!
document.getElementById(names[i]);
// Or a shortcut via jQuery (saving the extra variable):
application.parentNode.removeChild($(`#${names[i]}`));
```

Comment: I did not know that about IDs so I really appreciate your comment! As embarrassing as it is, I have simply been duplicating the name of the parent element (div for an application) as the class name of the check box and then that is what gets passed to the database which deletes any entries with the same company name. So when I get an element by ID, I am ACTUALLY getting the application wrapper which then gets deleted from the "applications-wrapper". I think a better approach would be to access the parent node of the checkboxes (actually parentNode of the parentNode) and get the proper ID.

Comment: Yes, that'd be better! You can also look into `uuid` aka how to generate unique IDs or hashes for each element.